# Bootstrap responsive layout challenge

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap but I can't get it to do what I want.

I want it to go from large screen like this

```
----------------------
Headline  |          |
          |  image   |
----------|          |
Bullet    |          |
list      |          |
----------|----------|
```

To this on a small screen

```
----------|
Headline  |           
          |           
----------|
          |
image     |
          |
          |
          |
----------|
bullet    |
list      |
          |
```

At the moment I can only get one of these to work e.g. when the small screen layout works the large screen layout looks like this

```
----------|----------|
Headline  |          |
          |  image   |
          |          |
          |          |
          |          |
----------|----------|
Bullet    |
list      |
          |
          |
```

The bullet list won't tuck up under the headline like in the first example. It's always after the image height.

See example code here:  http://jsfiddle.net/Jw4s9/1

Should I just use something like http://masonry.desandro.com/??

Comment: Could you post your markup ?

Comment: We need to see your code

Comment: @mouhammed Correct link is here http://jsfiddle.net/Jw4s9/1/

Comment: You should use Masonry. Check this answer : http://bit.ly/UTk48x

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that when you use a `row` atribute, it will create a new row, so you re a bit with limit in bootstrap on that part. You can do it with offsets and some margin stuff when you re on full screen and let bootstrap handle it when in lower resolutions, but you need set up a bunch of `@media queries`. If you re not limited to work with bootstrap only, please see Masonry! It does exactly what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to pull your image right at the md breakpoint, such as:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/3H52X/)

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .md-pull-right {
        float: right;    
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1>HEADER TEXT HERE</h1>
        <p class="lead">Some sub header text here.</p>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-4 md-pull-right">
        <img  src="http://www.lunkos.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/lolcat-faith-heealer.jpg" />
    </div>    
    <div class="col-md-8 lead">
        <ul>
            <li>1. Point number one</li>
            <li>2. Point number two</li>
            <li>3. Point number three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Also, you want the unordered list to be col-md-8 so that there is room for the image (i.e., it should be the same width as the header div).

Comment: Works a treat! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You just need to make a div that will complete the grid system, because right now you have 8 at the headline and 4 at the image. So just make a div with nothing in it after the image div, like in here: 
    jsfiddle.net/Jw4s9/6/

Comment: His column with width 4 specifies in bootstrap the width needed, no need to fill it up with an empty div. Plus this is not related to his issue. He needs the bullets to move up in the main screen, so his `lead` container needs to go up, but since he defined a 12 to it, and he already had 12 columns defined in his header and image together, the items is moved downwards.